# jenkins newly triggered build hangs waiting for its predecessor to finish while its predecessor has already finished

Tags: jenkins

I'm facing an issue with Jenkins matrix job, when I trigger new build run it hangs waiting for its predecessor to finish while its predecessor has already finished

Using: Jenkins 2.249.3

The hung build run shows the following message

```
16:07:59 Configuration ABC? test_check1,MAX=40 is still in the queue: Build #6,314 is already in progress (ETA: N/A)
```

Going to predecessor build link, shows that it has finished its run

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have a cleanWS step that's still processing?

Comment: yes, I have "Delete workspace when build is done". I will remove it an try.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed when enabled "Disable deferred wipeout" in the workspace cleanup post action